# Does Tor client connect to multiple Directory Servers?

Tags: directory

In my pcap file capturing Tor traffic, there are connections to 2 Directory Servers (x.x.x.x:9001 and y.y.y.y:443) and they started nearly at the same time.

My question is that is it normal or not? 
and why does Tor client connect to multiple Directory Servers?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's normal. The multiple connections to Directory servers and the nodes mirroring a signed image of Directory are for load balancing and censorship resistance purposes.

Comment: Do you have any links to sources to support your answer? (I'm not saying it's incorrect!) That way the OP can go away and read up on the exact details. Perhaps the Tor Directory Protocol specification?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks do you need a point in source? The protocol spec is not clarifying this matter, and for a good reason : it's *obvious*. The more directory sourcves we have - the safer we are